# Why does using bundles in MVC cause increased memory usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

We have updated various sites to version MCV4 and simultaneously we exploited the ability to create Bundle with dll System.Web.Optimization. Everything works.

However, we have the following problem:
when javascript is called the bundle of the application **allocates about 50 MB RAM**, without releasing it. The javascript included in the bundle have are in total about 2 Mb.

Note:
We create Bundles in global asax, the event "Application_Start"

```
   protected virtual void Application_Start()
        {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }



 protected virtual void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/all.css").Include(
                    "~/content/site.css"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/themes/base/base.all.css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css",
                    "~/content/themes/base/kendo.common.css",
                    "~/content/themes/base/kendo.totalcom.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.contextmenu.css",
                    "~/content/themes/base/tipsy.css",
                    "~/content/themes/base/jquery.ibutton.css"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/all.js").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js",
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                "~/Scripts/conditional-validation.js",
                "~/Scripts/fileuploader.js",
                "~/Content/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo.all.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.contextmenu.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.tipsy.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.checkradio.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.metadata.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.ibutton.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.easing.js",
                "~/Scripts/functions.js",
                "~/Scripts/Erp.js",
                "~/Scripts/Cms.js"
            ));
    }
```

The bundles are called in the masterpage

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/all.css") %>
<%: Styles.Render("~/content/themes/base/base.all.css") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/all.js") %>
```

EDIT:
when the following line is executed an extra 50mb memory is used

```
<%:
Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/all.js")
 %>
```

Has anyone else has run into this problem? Any suggestions to reduce this memory consumption?

Comment: I have same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280851/why-scripts-render-invoke-jsminify-process/24341774?noredirect=1#comment37641657_24341774

Comment: How is your application deployed? Is it on a single server, or are you using a service like azure that uses a distributed cache? Also, what version of MVC web optimization are you using?

Comment: @Jack Version 1.1 - Single server, no azure.  In production we use a web garden but I see this issue on my local system where there is only 1 w3wp.exe process

Comment: @theycallmemorty Oh ok, I thought it might be related to problems with a distributed cache or multiple threads.

Comment: @theycallmemorty, what version of the web optimization framework are you using?

Comment: also, are you running in debug mode? your problem is common on servers running debug mode. The number 45MB+ is also common, it is about the size of optimization dll

Comment: @DaveA problem is prevalent in release mode and debug mode - Using System.Web.Optimization version 1.1.

Comment: this problem was common. I would suggest upgrading to 1.3

Comment: @DaveA - What is the best way to determine the latest version? http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/ seems to say 1.1.3 is the latest.

Comment: My bad. I meant 1.1.3. here's the official page https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/

Comment: Have you checked whether the bundling works using your browser's developer tools or any monitoring tool such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network). Besides, have you checked your Web.config file that compilation tag is set to false (`<compilation debug="true" />`) so that bundling and minification will be enabled, or else you can add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to your `RegisterBundles` method to enable it.

Comment: Yes bundling is functioning correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had to deal with Bundles adding 200MB+ of memory to my IIS process when serving `kendo.all.js` (which is a staggering 5MB; the minified version is around 2MB), which is ridiculous. I plan on breaking that kendo file into several bundles and eliminating the controls I don't want, but I wanted to deal with that later.

In my case, I have both unminified and minified versions of the assets from the vendor. [I don't need Bundles to minify anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHXpV.png). All I need it to do is emit the direct links to the unminified scripts when `debug="true"` and emit a link to the bundle of concatenated but preminified scripts when `debug="false"`.

In my BundleConfig.cs, I had been using a `ScriptBundle` for my vendor files, which will attempt to minify, resulting in the cocked hat I've already mentioned. Using just plain old `Bundle` gives me the functionality I need without attempting to minify, and saving me a lot of memory. Sod off, `ScriptBundle`!

Comment: How did you find out the memory usage of the bundles? I'm having similar problems, and I think Bundling might be the culprit, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @Escobar5 At the time, I had mostly client script changes and it was the only server-side change. I noticed that the output of the bundles was severely mangled, so I reverted the change and the memory issue went away. I only looked into ScriptBundle vs Bundle enough to note the additional minification I didn't need, so I tried it with just Bundle and good enough.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: I had the same thing with kendoui.all in my bundle, but my bundle also included several other large-ish libs. It caused an additional 450MB(!) of memory usage - right when Scrips.Render was called (found by watching diag. tools)  Some seemed to be cleaned up after by GC, some not. EnableOptimizations on or off didn't matter. I ended up simply putting the old script tags back in and deleting bundle. With Web.Optimizations having not changed since 2014, I think we are dinosaurs. .Net Core does it differently, and many/most ppl seem to be moving to bundle in the design/build phase w. task runners

Answer (score 0):

Can you please enable optimization

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    // your bundling goes here

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```