# Why Scripts.Render invoke JsMinify.Process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, asp.net-mvc-5, bundle, webgrease

I profiled my ***ASP.NET MVC*** application and I saw strange a function calls.

You can see it on image

[image]

Always when mvc render layout we invoke `system.web.optimization.scripts.render` which invoke    `JsMinify.Process` and `Minifier.MinifyJavaScript`, but I thought what minification should be one time on the start app.

Am I right?

Maybe must I set some settings for optimization it?

Conditions:

- localhost
- release
- BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Comment: Do you know if this happens with the Release configuration as well?

Comment: I verified it only in localhost with Release config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great Question!

Intuitively, you are right, minification of assets should be performed on application ***Startup***. You assume that assets are delivered identically to all browsers. But Microsoft believes that much of JS and CSS is browser specific.

If you check asp.net site's reference on ***ASP.NET 4.5*** **[Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/hands-on-labs/whats-new-in-aspnet-and-web-development-in-visual-studio-2012#Exercise4)**, they specifically state:

> Bundling and minification in ASP.NET 4.5 is performed at runtime, so
>   that the process can identify the user agent (for example IE, Mozilla,
>   etc) , and thus, improve the compression by targeting the user browser
>   (for instance, removing stuff that is Mozilla specific when the
>   request comes from IE).

:

---

**What about caching?**

Bundling isn't as obtuse as a profiled would have you think. If you look up **[MVC 4 Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)** reference, they point out:

> Bundle Caching
>
> Bundles set the HTTP Expires Header one year from when the bundle is 
>   created. If you navigate to a previously viewed page, Fiddler shows IE
>   does not make a conditional request for the bundle, that is, there are
>   no HTTP GET requests from IE for the bundles and no HTTP 304 responses
>   from the server.

This is far more information than you need, but the message is that, JSMinify has a check for relevant cached minified assets.

When you factor in further that we already use minified version of our assets (eg jquery.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js), you can appreciate that .Net minification is a supplemental process.

Why does Minification of all types have to happen

Comment: Thanks. Why not create caching for browsers version on server?

Comment: @Mediator, I'm sure the cache is stored on the server. If you're asking why the server doesn't automatically create and cache every conceivable version of the cached minifications and bundle them, I can't be certain, but I suspect it's because there are too many potential versions of browsers to take into account. Such a job is probably too expensive to except as needed.

Comment: I looking through the source code and found settings for IE browsers =(. Thank you for answer. I will search solution for caching on an server for different versions browsers.